How to interpret Angular FormBuilder.group method signature
The question is very simple, but I still don't know the exact meaning. In Angular 5.2 FormBuilder group method,it shows.

(method) FormBuilder.group(controlsConfig: {
[key: string]: any; }, extra?: {
[key: string]: any; } | null): FormGroup

How to interpret this signature?
It receive an object named controlsConfig with key as string datatype, value as any datatype?
And an optional object parameter with name 'extra' with (key is string datatype, value is any datatype) or with extra parameter value = null?

You should be using the versions of angular that have LTS support, so try moving to higher version of angular like v15 or earlier. Since it contains important security and feature updates.

As seen in the source code of v5 form_builder.ts
Form builder Docs - v5
The first argument, is just the controls you supply to the form builder.
this.form = fb.group({
  name: fb.group({
    first: ['Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)],
    last: 'Drew',
  }),
  email: '',
});

Each key is the form control name and the value contains either the form control (new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2))) or the short hand method of declaring a form control ['Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)].
The second argument is mentioned in the docs as:

Valid keys for the extra parameter map are validator and asyncValidator.

So it must be like.
this.form = fb.group({
  name: fb.group({
    first: ['Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)],
    last: 'Drew',
  }),
  email: '',
}, { 
  validators: [this.someCustomValidator()],
  asyncValidator: [this.someCustomAsyncValidator()], 
});


but how your example map to the api signature?[ key: string] map to your 'first', 'last', 'email'? any map to your example ['Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)], 'Drew', ''?
then signature 'controlsConfig:' = ?

@user1169587 you are taking about the signature  { [key: string]: any }, so the LHS [key: string] which tells that the key will always be a string in my example it's first, last, etc. The RHS : any means the value can be of any type, it will accept both new FormControl() and ['Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)], the typing is not strictly typed so they have used any

then what is "controlsConfig:" means in controlsConfig: {
[key: string]: any;
}

@user1169587 Its just a internal name for the arguments, it does not really matter when we implement the function, since its used internally in angular, we can just focus on the type of the argument ( { [key: string]: any })

Oh, it is just an internal name? no any relationship with this ControlConfig (https://v17.angular.io/api/forms/ControlConfig)?

@user1169587 no, for formbuilder, it is not. since its a variable name, if it were, it would have been mentioned in the type of the property.

Ok, the syntax  { [key: string]: any; } is called index signatures for typescript.
